# property inside local date time in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

LocalDateTime as application.property

My application.properties looks like this:

> date.format='dd-MM-yyyy'

```
<p th:text="${#temporals.format(localDateTime, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></p>
```

How to replace 'dd-MM-yyyy' wit my property?

Comment: have you tried `<p th:text="${#temporals.format(localDateTime, @environment.getProperty('date.format')}"></p> )`

Comment: what is this @environment?

Comment: I need to specify it somewhere earlier?

Comment: you said you had declare it in application.properties , so @environment will access this file

Comment: nope it does not (unfortunately) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get property from `@environment`.

   ```
   @environment.getProperty('date.format')
   ```
2. But this will not solve it for you, next step is to preprocess this expression with `__` [notation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing)

   ```
   <p th:text="${#temporals.format(localDateTime, __${@environment.getProperty('date.format')}__)}">
   ```
3. But even this version will not work, because you format needs quotes
   `format(localDateTime, 'dd-MM-yyyy')` and you are passing
   `format(localDateTime, dd-MM-yyyy)` so **the final working version**
   should look like this:

   ```
   <p th:text="${#temporals.format(localDateTime, __${''''+@environment.getProperty('date.format')+''''}__)}">
   ```

So as you can see it is much easier to just pass format from controller)

Comment: numer 2 will work for me, because i set my property as:
date.time.format='dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' and not a date.time.format=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm

Comment: @degath yeah it depends on your property files. if you have quotes there, you can skip 3-d step

Comment: ofc your answer is really solid. I'll think about pass format from controller, but right now it works, so ofc I'll accept your answer. Thanks :)